# Which word defines noise that is loud, but less than a din?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for terms that define noise, as is particularly heard in a newspapaer office. It is loud, but not loud enough to be called a din/ruckus/cacophony.

Comment: You want a word for the more-or-less constant sound of a busy office where two people standing a few feet apart can still engage in a conversation without having to raise their voices?

Comment: @TimRomano yep that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Rathony I am looking for a word that describes a decibel lower than a din. Not the other way round. Thanks though. Any help is welcome.

Comment: A din doesn't have to be loud, it simply has to be annoying.

Comment: 'Din'  is a mass noun. There ain't one or more of them.

Comment: @Mitch: No it's not. Look at uses of the word, and you'll find "a din", "the din", "that din", and constructions like that. For example, see [both example sentences in the Merriam-Webster online entry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/din).

Comment: @2357112 and Mitch. It's one of the nouns that comes somewhere in between count and noncount nouns, taking an indefinite article but not numbers. Compare the usage of 'light' in 'there was a gentle light in the glade' etc.

Answer (score 15):

There is ['clamour' (US: 'clamor')](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clamour?s=t)

> Clamour - **noun**
>
> 1 - a loud uproar, as from a crowd of people: the clamor of the crowd at the gates.
>
> 4 - any loud and continued noise: the clamor of traffic; the clamor of birds and animals in the zoo.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

There is also ['hubbub'](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hubbub)

> Hubbub - **noun**
>
> 1 - a loud, confused noise, as of many voices: 
>   There was quite a hubbub in the auditorium after the announcement
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: hubbub is better :)

Comment: @A.P. You think it's mainly an American thing? :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, why? :) I just think of this word when I need to drown the office clamor with some music :)

Comment: Your US spelling!

Comment: I think of **clamor** as being too loud to satisfy the OP's request. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=shouted+over+the+clamor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cshouted%20over%20the%20clamor%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @TimRomano sadly there is no universally accepted scale of volume upon which all these terms neatly sit. However it has been possible to suggest synonyms from which the OP can select one that matches *their* interpretation of the volume scale :)

Comment: @Marv Mills:  Although I agree that there is no universally accepted scale of volume, I think native speakers do tend to think of **clamor** as being so loud that a normal conversation is impossible.  That's what I tried to show with the Ngram for `shouted over the clamor`

Comment: @TimRomano I don't think you can accept there is no universal agreement on the one hand and then claim a universal agreement on one term on the other hand :)

Comment: @Marv Mills: "native speakers *tend* to think" is hardly a claim of universal agreement.

Comment: I would definitely put a "clamour" as louder than a "din"

Comment: @TimRomano I agree, but you seem to be speaking for all native speakers as if there is consensus, but you have already agreed there isn't. Look, let's not descend to the number of angels dancing on the head of a pin-style arguments- there is no universally accepted scale which means there is no consensus- any number of people may offer their opinions on the relative loudness of terms that are not defined in that way but opinion is all it is. That is why I offer no such claim, merely suggestions that the OP may select according to their internal scale, or not as the case may be..

Comment: @Marv Mills: it could be the word **clamor** is undergoing a semantic change and isn't as associated with loud noises as it once was. It seems to be becoming less "deafening": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deafening+clamor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeafening%20clamor%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @Tim Romano I consider you're more right than I was.  +1 for 'hubbub' instead.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: I can remember a much quieter world.

Comment: Zawa...za...zawa...

Answer (score 8):

Agree with Marv that clamor and hubbub are nice ones for the sustained noise of voices in a room.

You might also consider **racket**, which I think suggests a more abrasive sound than either of the above, perhaps one punctuated by the tapping of journalists fingers on keyboards.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/racket

> *noun*
>
> 1 :  confused clattering noise :  clamor
>
> 2 a :  social whirl or excitement

Comment: I think "racket" indicates a noise so loud that it is extremely annoying to others. I think the OP is looking for something milder.

Answer (score 8):

Although Oxford Dictionary’s entry for “**[buzz](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/buzz)**” includes the notion of “continuous”:

> 1A  low, continuous humming or murmuring sound, made by or similar to
>   that made by an insect: the buzz of the bees **a buzz of
>   conversation**;

I usually use, perhaps redundantly, and see it with “constant” (which I suppose makes this a two-word answer), as in this example from ‘[The Smouldering Flame](https://books.google.com/books?id=i2s5BAAAQBAJ&pg=PT68&lpg=PT68&dq=hard+to+talk+above+the+%22constant+buzz%22&source=bl&ots=E_T6P4OWYt&sig=NbfQShcb1AYT5KMyBe15mNt6yE0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCcQ6AEwAmoVChMIzouR1YjyyAIVAhUeCh3gPgQS#v=onepage&q=%22constant%20buzz%22&f=false)’ by Anne Mather (via Google Books):

> … she doubted if he had even heard her above the **constant buzz** of
>   conversation all around them.”

Answer (score 7):

A "[dull roar](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dull+roar)"?

> *n.* a relatively quiet degree of noisiness.

Answer (score 5):

More suggestions - **Rumble:**

> a low heavy continuous reverberating often muffled sound (as of thunder) - [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rumble)

Or **Clatter:**

> **1**. a rattling sound (as of hard bodies striking together)
>
> **2**. commotion
>
> **3**. noisy chatter -*[Ibid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clatter)*.

From which, **Commotion:**

> **4. a** :  an agitated disturbance :  to-do
>
> **b**.  :  noisy confusion :  agitation - *[Ibid](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commotion)*.

Answer (score 4):

If it's a modern-day newspaper office, you won't have the sound of typewriter keys being struck, but the sound of people's voices.

You could refer to the **constant chatter** of the newspaper office.

Answer (score 1):

Consider **murmur**:

> a low, indistinct, continuous sound, as of a stream, far-off voices, etc.

(http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/murmur)

If a short phrase is acceptable, how about **speech noise**:

> Coping with **Speech Noise** in the Modern Workplace

(http://chatterblocker.com/whitepapers/conversational_distraction.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Hustle and Bustle** - energy and excitement; confusion and business

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hustle+and+bustle

Answer (score -2):

**Cacophony** might express the sound you are trying to describe, but it must be discordant in addition to loud.

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you suggest this term, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: -1 The OP has already rules out 'cacophony'